# How to put marker on time series training set

Tags: time-series, recurrent-neural-network

My input is this picture
[image: time series input]

And I would like to put markers on it and use time series with markers as a label
[image: time series lable]

Two picture are not scaled. Main point is I would like to train RNN classifier and let it be able to mark the starting points and stopping points.

More generalized examples
[image: More generalized example]

**Question**
What is the best function to be marker encoding function?

Comment: Looks like a velocity trace.  Why do you need a complicated network for this?  You should be able to just set a threshold value based off of a sliding window, for example.

Comment: Because size is not the same for each graph and I want to apply A.I. to this problem. Thank you for your attention ;)

Comment: Do you have a lot of them already manually marked to train on or do you want it to somehow learn these on its own?

Comment: @neuroguy123 Thank you for you kind attentions. This question is solved by splitting my problem into 2 parts. First part is classification single pulse, multiple pulses, ... etc. Second starting point and stopping point detection.